# A simple error with stochastic variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

```
f = Piecewise[{
    {0.1, x == 1 && y == 1}, {0.1, x == 2 && y == 1}, {0.0, 
     x == 3 && y == 1}, {0.3, x == 1 && y == 2}, {0.1, 
     x == 2 && y == 2}, {0.2, x == 3 && y == 2}, {0.0, 
     x == 1 && y == 3}, {0.2, x == 2 && y == 3}, {0.1, 
     x == 3 && y == 3}, {0, True}}];
fi = ProbabilityDistribution[f, {x, 1, 3, 1}, {y, 1, 3, 1}];
Probability[
 x <= 2 && y <= 2, {x \[Distributed] fi, y \[Distributed] fi}]
```

I am trying to compute this problem. The result I am looking for is 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probability distribution is not valid.
This can be seen:

```
Probability[x > 0 || y > 0, {x, y} \[Distributed] fi]
```

which yields  1.1 and can be seen by looking at the definition of the PMF:

```
PDF[fi, {x, y}]
```

This is probably a small error you can correct.  Once you correct f, you can call the probability for the joint distribution (below is still erroneous):

```
f = Piecewise[{{0.1, x == 1 && y == 1}, {0.1, x == 2 && y == 1}, {0.0,
      x == 3 && y == 1}, {0.3, x == 1 && y == 2}, {0.1, 
     x == 2 && y == 2}, {0.2, x == 3 && y == 2}, {0.0, 
     x == 1 && y == 3}, {0.2, x == 2 && y == 3}, {0.1, 
     x == 3 && y == 3}, {0, True}}];
fi = ProbabilityDistribution[f, {x, 1, 3, 1}, {y, 1, 3, 1}];
Probability[x <= 2 && y <= 2, {x, y} \[Distributed] fi]
```

Comment: How would you compute: $P((X \leq 2 ) \cup ( Y\leq 2 ))$

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thanks a lot!